# Use of Murmurhash in C

Tags: c, hash

I am in the process of implementing a hash table and hence hash function in C and heard that Murmurhash was a suitably fast algorithm for this purpose. Looking up some C code for this provided:

```
uint32_t murmur3_32(const char *key, uint32_t len, uint32_t seed) {
    static const uint32_t c1 = 0xcc9e2d51;
    static const uint32_t c2 = 0x1b873593;
    static const uint32_t r1 = 15;
    static const uint32_t r2 = 13;
    static const uint32_t m = 5;
    static const uint32_t n = 0xe6546b64;

    uint32_t hash = seed;

    const int nblocks = len / 4;
    const uint32_t *blocks = (const uint32_t *) key;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nblocks; i++) {
        uint32_t k = blocks[i];
        k *= c1;
        k = (k << r1) | (k >> (32 - r1));
        k *= c2;

        hash ^= k;
        hash = ((hash << r2) | (hash >> (32 - r2))) * m + n;
    }

    const uint8_t *tail = (const uint8_t *) (key + nblocks * 4);
    uint32_t k1 = 0;

    switch (len & 3) {
    case 3:
        k1 ^= tail[2] << 16;
    case 2:
        k1 ^= tail[1] << 8;
    case 1:
        k1 ^= tail[0];

        k1 *= c1;
        k1 = (k1 << r1) | (k1 >> (32 - r1));
        k1 *= c2;
        hash ^= k1;
    }

    hash ^= len;
    hash ^= (hash >> 16);
    hash *= 0x85ebca6b;
    hash ^= (hash >> 13);
    hash *= 0xc2b2ae35;
    hash ^= (hash >> 16);

    return hash;
}
```

I was wondering if I could clarify a few things with regard to the arguments that are being passed here. "Key" is obviously the string that you are hashing. If this is defined in a struct as having an array length of 46, would this be the value that I would pass as "length" in the above function? The argument "seed", I take it this can be any arbitrary value as long it stays constant between hash calls? Are there any other parameters that I need to change keeping in mind that I am working on a 32-bit machine?

I take it I will also need to modulo the return hash by the size of my hash table?

In addition, if anyone could recommend a superior/faster alternative hash function used for strings then that would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes (but use `sizeof` instead so you won't make mistakes). Yes. Probably not. Yes.

Comment: `const uint32_t *blocks = (const uint32_t *) key;` This assumes that key is aligned sufficiently to be cast to a 32bit pointer. For a char pointer this cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: @wildplasser architecture-dependent, no problem on *x86* afaik ... but good point.

Comment: *at least* a performance penalty. (and relevant, since the OP is overly concerned with performance) Unaligned bus access can be costly, maybe costly enough to nihilate the gain of operating on 32 bits chunks)

Answer (score 1):

About the question regarding the parameters: yes, just read the code, your assumptions are correct.

You don't need modulo as long as the size of your hash table is a power of 2. Then you can just use a bitmask, e.g. (pseudocode)

```
void* hashtbl[1<<8]; /* 256 */

int key = hash(value, ...) & ((1<<8) - 1); /* 0xff */
```

Then keep in mind that performance is not the only relevant characteristic of a hash function. It's very important to get an equal distribution of the whole key space. I can't tell you how "good" *murmurhash* is in that respect, but probably much better than a very simple hashing I used resently for playing around a bit:

```
static unsigned int
hash(const void *key, size_t keyLen, unsigned int hashmask)
{
    size_t i;
    unsigned int h = 5381;

    for (i=0; i<keyLen; ++i)
    {
        h += (h << 5) + ((const unsigned char *)key)[i];
    }

    return h & hashmask;
}
```

although this simple function is probably faster. It's a tradeoff and a "clever" hashing algorithm tries to be as fast as possible while still giving good distribution. The simplistic function above doesn't really give good distribution, for example it will never use the whole key space for small input (less than 5 bytes).

Comment: `... & (1<<8 - 1)` *is* still computing the hash modulo the size of the hash table, just without using the % operator.

Comment: @immibis it masks bits and the result *happens* to be that of *modulo 256* -- that's the point of it ...

Comment: You said you "don't need modulo" - just pointing out that you're still performing a modulo operation (without using the % operator which exists for that purpose).

Comment: @immibis still, I don't. The operation is masking bits. It's an *equivalent* operation, but the CPU is doing something different, much simpler. (which I could write `%256` of course, because I'd assume a good compiler would see the equivalence and optimize accordingly)

Comment: `1 << 8 - 1` parses as `1 << (8 - 1)`.

Comment: @melpomene fixed, thanks (was just untested pseudo code ...)